# How to modify a function in local R package?

Tags: r, package

I have an R package made by someone else. I want to add an additional function to it, how can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

To change a function from a given package, you'll probably need `trace` function, it helps you edit and modify a function `F`

```
trace("F",edit=TRUE)
```

it will open a small window for you to modify the code, but it won't change the actual source code permanently.
you can copy and paste the code and create a new function with your own modifications.

Comment: Thank you. how can I create and add  the new function to the package?

Comment: @PariT The easier way is to copy the source code of function into an R-script, make your modifications, save it as a new function and use that one from your own source code without being in any package. if you want to change the code in the package take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295279/r-how-do-i-add-an-extra-function-to-a-package

Comment: This post does not say about the general way how to add a new function to an R package. Do you know how to do that? I am using the function within a team therefore it would be easier if it is included in the package.

Comment: @PariT I think `fix()` will do it for you if you want to modify a currently existing function https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/fix.html