# read-only glasses icon appear in r functions in rstudio

Tags: r, function, rstudio, readonly

*Background:* If you want to modify one of your customly defined functions, you can access the source code by selecting the function name and press "F2", or ctrl-click it. This will take you to the function source and you can make changes.

*Problem:* You are redirected to a read-only definition of your function (indicated by read-only glasses icon appearing in the tab in rstudio) instead of your source script. (This is a similar behaviour as if you were inspecting a function loaded from a package or base R.)

*Question:* What should I do to remove the read-only mode? I want to be able to edit the functions again.

I would like to know what I could have done to run into the aforementioned problem, not to do it again.

Comment: I assume you mean the glasses symbol. You are viewing a function, just the same as you view a data frame. You can't edit that in a `View` call. Edit the source of the function, and re-write it into your environment.

Comment: @Anonymouscoward   I wonder if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276439/how-to-modify-a-function-in-local-r-package is in the directions you point. In addition, what might have done to run into the problem I describe? I do not want to do it again.

Comment: I ran into this behaviour unexpectedly with one of my own functions. Turns out that if the source file and the loaded function are not identical (if, for example, you loaded the function and then modified and saved the source), you will see the loaded version, which can't be modified. Seems to be a similar behaviour if you work with a project and source a file outside the project folder.

Original post: https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-does-rstudio-open-a-function-in-view-mode-when-requested-go-to-function-definition/94135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does provide directions to edit pre-built functions from packages. If this is a function you have created, then the part about copy/paste/edit would suffice to redefine the function.

In your case, view whatever the function is (I made this one up), copy it into your console and change it as you please.

```
> View(mathFunction)

function(x,y,...) {sum(x, y, ...)} # this will show up in a window.

> mathFunction <- function(x,y,..., digits = z) {round(sum(x, y, ...), digits = z)} # redefine it
```