# How to modify pre-existing function in local environment in R

Tags: r, function, package

I am trying to modify an existing function by copy and pasting it to an R script, and assigning it to a new function object in my local environment. However the new function cannot find functions that are called to within the original function. How can I fix this without looking up and finding each function individually? I am guessing that the original function is somehow linked to the package or its dependencies and 'knows where to look' for the missing function, but I cannot figure out how to do this with my new copy-and-pasted function.

```
library("camtrapR")
```

Print the function name

```
activityDensity
```

The output here is the code for this function. I have omitted it here because it is long (and I have pasted it below), but I copy and paste the output of the function code exactly (see below where I assign this exact code to a new function), except for the last two lines of output, which I think are important:

```
<bytecode: 0x000000002a2d1e20>
<environment: namespace:camtrapR>
```

So now I assign the copy and pasted code from the output above to a new function with `New <-`

```
   New <- function (recordTable, species, allSpecies = FALSE, speciesCol = "Species", 
          recordDateTimeCol = "DateTimeOriginal", recordDateTimeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 
          plotR = TRUE, writePNG = FALSE, plotDirectory, createDir = FALSE, 
          pngMaxPix = 1000, add.rug = TRUE, ...) 
{
  wd0 <- getwd()
  mar0 <- par()$mar
  on.exit(setwd(wd0))
  on.exit(par(mar = mar0), add = TRUE)
  recordTable <- dataFrameTibbleCheck(df = recordTable)
  timeZone <- "UTC"
  checkForSpacesInColumnNames(speciesCol = speciesCol, recordDateTimeCol = recordDateTimeCol)
  if (!is.data.frame(recordTable)) 
    stop("recordTable must be a data frame", call. = FALSE)
  if (!speciesCol %in% colnames(recordTable)) 
    stop(paste("speciesCol = \"", speciesCol, "\" is not a column name in recordTable", 
               sep = ""), call. = FALSE)
  if (!recordDateTimeCol %in% colnames(recordTable)) 
    stop(paste("recordDateTimeCol = \"", recordDateTimeCol, 
               "\" is not a column name in recordTable", sep = ""), 
         call. = FALSE)
  stopifnot(is.logical(c(allSpecies, writePNG, plotR, createDir)))
  if (allSpecies == FALSE) {
    stopifnot(species %in% recordTable[, speciesCol])
    stopifnot(hasArg(species))
  }
  recordTable$DateTime2 <- parseDateTimeObject(inputColumn = recordTable[, 
                                                                         recordDateTimeCol], dateTimeFormat = recordDateTimeFormat, 
                                               timeZone = timeZone)
  recordTable$Time2 <- format(recordTable$DateTime2, format = "%H:%M:%S", 
                              usetz = FALSE)
  recordTable$Time.rad <- (as.numeric(as.POSIXct(strptime(recordTable$Time2, 
                                                          format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = timeZone))) - as.numeric(as.POSIXct(strptime("0", 
                                                                                                                                 format = "%S", tz = timeZone))))/3600 * (pi/12)
  if (isTRUE(writePNG)) {
    if (hasArg(plotDirectory)) {
      if (isTRUE(createDir)) {
        dir.create(plotDirectory, recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)
        setwd(plotDirectory)
      }
      else {
        stopifnot(file.exists(plotDirectory))
        setwd(plotDirectory)
      }
    }
    else {
      stop("writePNG is TRUE. Please set plotDirectory", 
           call. = FALSE)
    }
  }
  pngWidth <- pngMaxPix
  pngHeight <- round(pngMaxPix * 0.8)
  if (allSpecies == FALSE) {
    subset_species <- subset(recordTable, recordTable[, speciesCol] == 
                               species)
    if (nrow(subset_species) == 1) 
      stop(paste(species, "had only 1 record. Cannot estimate density."), 
           call. = FALSE)
    try_error_tmp <- try({
      if (isTRUE(writePNG)) 
        png(filename = paste("activity_density_", 
                             species, "_", Sys.Date(), ".png", 
                             sep = ""), width = pngWidth, height = pngHeight, 
            units = "px", res = 96, type = "cairo")
      if (isTRUE(writePNG) | isTRUE(plotR)) {
        densityPlot(subset_species$Time.rad, main = paste("Activity of", 
                                                          species), rug = add.rug, ...)
        mtext(paste("number of records:", nrow(subset_species)), 
              side = 3, line = 0)
      }
      if (isTRUE(writePNG)) 
        dev.off()
    }, silent = TRUE)
    if (class(try_error_tmp) == "try-error") 
      warning(paste(toupper(species), ": ", try_error_tmp[1], 
                    "    - SKIPPED", sep = ""), call. = FALSE)
  }
  else {
    subset_species_list <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(unique(recordTable[, speciesCol]))) {
      spec.tmp <- unique(recordTable[, speciesCol])[i]
      subset_species <- subset(recordTable, recordTable[, 
                                                        speciesCol] == spec.tmp)
      plot_main_title <- paste("Activity of", spec.tmp)
      if (nrow(subset_species) == 1) {
        warning(paste(toupper(spec.tmp), ": It had only 1 record. Cannot estimate density.   - SKIPPED", 
                      sep = ""), call. = FALSE)
        next
      }
      else {
        try_error_tmp <- try({
          if (isTRUE(writePNG)) 
            png(filename = paste("activity_density_", 
                                 spec.tmp, "_", Sys.Date(), ".png", 
                                 sep = ""), width = pngWidth, height = pngHeight, 
                units = "px", res = 96, type = "cairo")
          if (isTRUE(writePNG) | isTRUE(plotR)) {
            densityPlot(subset_species$Time.rad, main = plot_main_title, 
                        rug = add.rug, ...)
            mtext(paste("number of records:", nrow(subset_species)), 
                  side = 3, line = 0)
          }
          if (isTRUE(writePNG)) 
            dev.off()
        }, silent = TRUE)
        if (class(try_error_tmp) == "try-error") 
          warning(paste(toupper(spec.tmp), ": ", 
                        try_error_tmp[1], "    - SKIPPED", 
                        sep = ""), call. = FALSE)
      }
      subset_species_list[[i]] <- subset_species$Time.rad
      names(subset_species_list)[i] <- spec.tmp
    }
  }
  if (allSpecies == FALSE) {
    return(invisible(subset_species$Time.rad))
  }
  else {
    return(invisible(subset_species_list))
  }
}
```

Yet, when I try to run this new function (arguments omitted here for clarity), it can't find a function embedded within.

**How can I somehow assign this function to look within the original package `camtrapR` for any dependencies, etc.? and why does the code output from the function not already do this?**

```
New()

Error in dataFrameTibbleCheck(df = recordTable) : 
  could not find function "dataFrameTibbleCheck"
```

This answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49277036/9096420 allows one to manually edit and save a function's code for each R session, but it is non-reproducible (not code) that can be shared or re-used.

Comment: assign the environment i.e. `environment(New) <- environment(oldFn)` after you have defined it, or else prepend each internal function with `package:::` or xhuck it all in a new package

Comment: I knew it was going to be simple - just one of those things that I couldn't find! Thank you. Yes, I figured I could use `package::` for each function, but didn't want to search for where they all came from.

Comment: Are you looking for a `hijack` function?  I've found this - https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/hijacking-r-functions-changing-default-arguments-3/ - useful in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `New` is the new function copied from camtrapR then use

```
environment(New) <- asNamespace("camtrapR")
```

to ensure that the function calls in its body are looked up in the correct places.